# Problems formatting tooltip date on HighStock chart

Tags: json, date, highcharts

I'm having an issue trying to get my dates formatted correctly with a highstock chart.

I have tried setting both xDateFormat and plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.dateTimeLabelFormat , but my dates are always show up like this:

> Mon May 6th 00:00:00 PDT 2012

I have a feeling is is something to do with how i am parsing dates. When i use an ISO 8601 date and create it via `new Date('2012-12-17T00:00:00')` i get incorrect formatting, but if I return a string such as `Date.UTC(2012,12,17)` and call `Eval()` on it, the formatting shows up as expected.

Here is an example of my implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/wGu9x/7/

Any insight into what is going on?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts use timestamps (time in miliseconds) So when you use Date.UTC() correct time is returned. (You don't need to use eval()).

Comment: Thanks, i just figured that out as well. Using Date.parse() now - which returns a timestamp, too.